# Angular - RxJS - How to perform actions for the filtered items in chain?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I have a pipe like this:

```
this.parentFormControl.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    tap(() => {
      this.focusIndex = -1;
    }),
    filter(() => this.myCondition()),
    switchMap((value: string) => {
      return this.http.get(value).pipe(catchError(err => {
        this.myErrorFunction(err);
        return EMPTY;
      }));
    })
  )
```

And i would like to perform some other 'side' actions like in the tap operator, for the items which are filtered -removed- (which returned 'false' from 'myCondition()' so to speak) How do i do it?

Comment: you can add a tap after the filter, or after the switchmap.

Comment: but i thought after the filter are just the items, which pass the filter? That is the point of filter no?

Comment: ahhh, you mean for elements that will be *removed* by the filter, sorry, I understood it the other way round.

Comment: sorry for the confusion.. i improved the question a bit

Comment: I edited my answer. You could repeat the test for the element in the tap before the filter.

Answer (score 3):

You can split the chain using `multicast` and then add `tap` for both conditions and after that simply ignore results you don't want:

```
range(1, 10)
  .pipe(
    multicast(() => new Subject(),
      o => merge(
        o.pipe(
          filter(v => v % 2 === 0),
          tap(v => console.log('true', v)),
        ),
        o.pipe(
          filter(v => v % 2 !== 0),
          tap(v => console.log('false', v)),
          ignoreElements(),
        ),
      )
    ),
  )
  .subscribe(v => console.log('result', v));
```

It's a bit long but it properly splits the source into two chains.

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-yarhux?file=index.ts

Comment: never saw `multicast` before, sounds like a good example ! However, I'm always "afraid" of memory leaks with Observables not properly "released" (mostly because of lack of understanding). Should we do something special to do some cleanup, for instance in `ngOnDestroy`, in order to properly clean the Subject created?

Comment: @Pac0 It's very unlikely there's any memory leak in `multicast` because this operator is used internally in `publish()` for example. However you should unsubscribe from this chain if you don't need it any more. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription

Answer (score 2):

You can add the condition to test in your tap before the filter.

```
this.parentFormControl.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    tap((x) => {
      this.focusIndex = -1;
      if (!this.myCondition()) console.log(x); // here
    }),
    filter(() => this.myCondition()),
    switchMap((value: string) => {
      return this.http.get(value).pipe(catchError(err => {
        this.myErrorFunction(err);
        return EMPTY;
      }));
    })
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `partition` (https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/partition) to split your stream into the result of filtering and what was filtered out.

```
const [result$, filteredOut$] = partition(source, (value) => myCondition(value));

// Observable w/ everything filtered out
result$.pipe( ... business as usual ... ).subscribe();

// Observable w/ what was filtered out
filteredOut$.pipe( ... taps, etc ... ).subscribe();
```